# C# Background worker Curiosity <CPU usage as viewed from Task Manager>

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

Recently I was programming a fun app to insert 1 Million random records in a MySQL database. I noticed that when I called the method to insert those 1M records from the main thread the C.P.U usage by my fun app (viewed from task manager) ranged somewhere between 65% and 85% and when the method was called from a background worker the usage was very low raging between 7% and 12%. Does high cpu usage mean that more is being processed at a time and is it safe to assume that the 1M records inserted by the main thread will finish long before the ones inserted by the background worker?

Also but not necessary is there a way to speed up the background worker, so it uses more cpu and completes faster?

Comment: Requests to insert items into a database is IO bound work.  If it's using up a lot of CPU time then it means that you're doing something very wrong,

Comment: Nothing unusual, just the usual insert into

Comment: And that doesn't take much of any CPU power; the network is the bottleneck.  If you're using up a lot of CPU time doing that kind of work then it's not doing anything productive.  You should be trying to figure out how to minimize the CPU utilization while still keeping the execution time about the same, which should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: right.. so % represents cpu time used? and not power or speed

Comment: It's the inverse of the percentage of noops the CPU is performing over a given time period.

Comment: I had to go and read up on that but... I get it now, thanks.